# Apply groupby on multiple columns while taking aggregate in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to apply a groupby to multiple columns while running an aggregate function.

**Data**

```
country type    en  start   
Japan   aa      25  8/1/2022    
Japan   cc      1   9/1/2022    
US      bb      5   8/1/2022    
US      bb      5   8/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
country type    en  start    
Japan   aa      25  8/1/2022    
Japan   cc      1   9/1/2022    
US      bb      10  8/1/2022
```

**Doing**

```
df.groupby(['country','type','date'])['en'].sum()
```

However, this is creating some blank rows. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Naveed  the date is part of the groupby.. so if same country has same date, same type, we sum the en column.

Comment: are you sure the rows are blank and not just displaying as a hierarchical index? If it's the latter, setting the `styler.sparse.index` option to True would fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out=df.groupby(['country','type','start'], as_index=False).agg({'en': sum})
out
```

```
country     type    start   en
0   Japan   aa  8/1/2022    25
1   Japan   cc  9/1/2022    1
2   US      bb  8/1/2022    10
```

Comment: wonder could you groupby date as well, I think it is more accurate - because we group by date type and country, then take sum of en col

Comment: just updated the solution

Comment: @Lynn, what you had as a solution was just as good as mine. Why was it failing?

Comment: yes but my rows were coming up blank - it grouped by the country but it produced blank rows